# What node type will getElementsByTagName return?

Tags: java, xml

I am new here.
I have seen several Java examples on xml processing.
They often do something like :

```
NodeList nl = Document.getElementsByTagName("xxxxxxxx");
If (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
{
    ......
}
```

Question:
Do i really need to check the node type?
Won't it be always an Element ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:
org.apache.xerces.dom.DeepNodeImpl.java

```
nextMatchingElementAfter(Node c)
```

There is a exlicit check for the Node.Element_Node.

So you can expect Nodes from type Element from getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that validations makes any sense due the definition of the getElementsByTagName method

A new NodeList object containing all the matched Elements.

[Document specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String))